# How to commit a file to SVN inside a Maven plugin?

Tags: svn, maven-2, maven

how can I commit a file to SVN inside a Maven plugin ?

I have a selfwritten maven plugin which manipulates a file, which is already SVN supported.

After manipulation I would like to commit the changed file to SVN while being in the maven plugin ?

Can I just use some existing Maven-SVN-APIs inside my Java Code of the maven plugin ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I would strongly suggest to avoid such automated commits to SVN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should let Maven inject a ScmManager in your plugin

```
/**
 * @component
 */
protected ScmManager scmManager;
```

And with the ScmManager you can do many things.

Take a look into the [guide](http://maven.apache.org/scm/guide/usage.html). You don't need to do nativ SVNKit...Maven has already an abstraction layer for handling all version control tools.

Comment: thank you - I have also found this link... But what artifact(s) do I have to include ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Maven plugin, you can do whatever is possible with Java. http://svnkit.com/ is an excellent Java SVN library. It should be easy to commit a file.